# Code Coverage for Typescript

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, typescript

We've just started a project in Typescript and we need to get code coverage figures.

Our existing JavaScript projects use Instanbul in Grunt for coverage. We are unsure how to replicate this for TypeScript.

Are there any tools for generating code coverage from the TypeScript code itself?
Or do we run the Istanbul (or similar) tool against the generated JavaScript code.

Comment: Too bad this is closed. As of July 2017 [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) seems to be moved to [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc), so use nyc instead.

Answer (score 22):

On the TypeScript team, we just use regular code coverage tools on the compiled JavaScript. We've found this to be more than sufficient, since usually for code coverage you are looking at total coverage % (which doesn't change significantly) or are deep-diving at expression-level (which also doesn't change significantly).

If you found a tool that supported it (I'm not aware of any yet), you could in theory use the source maps emitted by the compiler to map the coverage data back to the TypeScript code. It's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: We started using that method, but when using modules with same prefixes: myApp.directives and myApp.services, the generated JS code ends with lines that are not covered: (myApp || (myApp = {}));

Did you find a way around it, so these branches are not marked as "not covered" in the coverage report?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-coverage-source-map

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work when your tests against the Typescript source via `ts-node`; dying to find some solution for this.

Answer (score 21):

### Update: August 2016

It is now possible to run Istanbul against TypeScript source code using [Istanbul v1](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/tree/v1.1.0-alpha.1) (currently in the alpha stage) along with [TypeScript Node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

The following assumes that you are using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) as a test framework and that all test code is under the standard `test/` directory.

First, install the requisite packages:

```
npm install --save-dev mocha ts-node
npm install --save-dev --save-exact istanbul@1.1.0-alpha.1
```

Then include something like the following in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "istanbul cover -e .ts _mocha -- --compilers ts:ts-node/register"
}
```

That's it. Run `npm test` and you'll be covered.

See my [Deep Map](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/deep-map/blob/cedccdca85d099aed289d3a75426c8adca285922/package.json#L12) project for a working example in which the test files are kept in the same directory as the source code. Here is a sample of the HTML output:

[image: Deep Map coverage]

Comment: How would we do this with Karma?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I expected someone would ask about Karma. I don't know, but I'll look into it and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Please ping me if and when you update your answer.

Comment: What is the `-e` option in istanbul? It doesn't appear in the `istanbul help cover` command.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin The `-e` option (apparently) registers the `.ts` *extension*. There may be more to it than that, but if there is, then you would have to go to the [Istanbul repository](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/tree/v1.1.0-alpha.1) and consult the source code or open an issue. As to your first question, I still intend to see if this can be done using Karma. But I'm no Karma expert, so you might have better luck posting a separate, Karma-specific question.

Comment: It's a shame that it doesn't appear to be entirely correct. For example, in your screenshot it says you've got 17/18 branches, but it doesn't point out which branches are uncovered - I'm guessing they're not branches in the TypeScript source. It does funky stuff for me, too. Even though I think I should be at 100%, I see stuff like this: http://imgur.com/W5Er208

Comment: @Vincent The example above is correct; the image above is just an excerpt, and the uncovered line is identified correctly elsewhere. But this answer needs to be updated, which I will do shortly. I'm not sure if it will fix your problem.

Comment: Hmm OK, then perhaps it's something weird about my setup after all. I'm looking forward to your update, hopefully it addressees it.

Comment: I get a deprecation warning for --compilers flag, any idea on what to replace it with?

Answer (score 13):

Two years after this question originally was posted, there is now `remap-istanbul` which seems promising.

you can read more about it in Sitepen: [Code Coverage for TypeScript and Other Transpiled Languages](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/09/29/code-coverage-for-typescript-and-other-transpiled-languages/)

As they write in the [Github project](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul):

> A package that provides the ability to remap Istanbul code coverage
>   information to its original source positions based on a JavaScript
>   Source Maps v3.

As I read the documentation, the project will take your istanbul-generated coverage as input for conversion based on the sourcemap. This sounds like an additional step, but I am sure it will benefit so that you can get rid of those transpiled autogenerated lines in the coverage report.

I believe this is exactly what you will need.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) for that

With Chutzpah you can run your tests from command line and integrate your tests with Visual Studio Test Explorer.

Chutzpah allows you decide if you want to run the tests from .ts files, .js files, .html files or from all of them.

When set (in Visual Studio/Tools/Options/Chutzpah) to run tests from .ts files, you will be able to analyze code coverage of your generated .js files, with a link between the generated JavaScript code and the .ts file that generated it.

It makes really easy to work on your TypeScript code coverage, even being the JavaScript code the real code under test.

You can install Chutzpah from Visual Studio/Tools/Extensions and updates.

You can find [here](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/chutzpah-2-4-code-coverage-is-a-go/) more details about code coverage using Chutzpah.

Comment: Thanks. We've gone with Chutzpah here and it's working fine for us.

Comment: Chutzpah appears to be for Visual Studio only.  TypeScript is not.

Comment: This should definitely not be the answer. the updated answer below should be.

Answer (score 7):

Run code coverage against the generated javascript. You can even hit 100% coverage by telling Istanbul to ignore those pesky impossible-to-call lines that typescript writes.

Istanbul honors comments like /* istanbul ignore next */, so what I do is run a string replace in my gulp task that injects the istanbul ignore comments into the auto-generated wrapper code that TypeScript writes.

Here is the gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    //compile typescript into javascript
    gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            declarationFiles: false,
            removeComments: false
        }))

        //write comments to tell istanbul to ignore the code inside the iife parameters
        .js.pipe(replace(/(}\)\()(.*\|\|.*;)/g, '$1/* istanbul ignore next */$2'))

        //write comments to tell istanbul to ignore the extends code that typescript generates
        .pipe(replace(/(var __extends = \(this && this.__extends\))/g, '$1/* istanbul ignore next */'))

        //write all of the compiled javascript files to a build folder so we can use them for tests and coverage
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src'))

        //...the rest of your build process
});
```

Here is the generated code.

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends)/* istanbul ignore next */ || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var animalApi;
(function (animalApi) {
    var dogs;
    (function (dogs) {
        var BlackLab = (function (_super) {
            __extends(BlackLab, _super);
            //class code...
        });
        dogs.BlackLab = BlackLab;
    })(/* istanbul ignore next */dogs = animalApi.dogs || (animalApi.dogs = {}));
})(/* istanbul ignore next */animalApi || (animalApi = {}));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Totally helpful.

Comment: Info: This is not needed! You can use tslib for that and turn off the code generation in your tsconfig
        //write comments to tell istanbul to ignore the extends code that typescript generates

Comment: @MarcoKlein Could you provide an example of what you are describing?

Comment: Sure! tsConfig:
      "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
     }

Then include https://github.com/Microsoft/tslib into your html above all of your ts-scripts and you just got rid of any overhead that typescript generates :)

Answer (score 2):

i have created sample to generate code coverage for typescript files using karma coverage and karma typescript processor.

https://github.com/nitinbhatia-dev/karma-typescript-coverage